# Are the ebs volumes used by the instances launched by an autoscaling group deleted when the instances are replaced/terminated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have an auto-scaling group with 2 instances.

Every time an instance is launched an EBS volume is attached to it. When it is replaced/terminated is the EBS volume deleted ?

I want to keep a tight budget on my account and I dont want to have volumes lingering and pay for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure it both ways. If you are using the web interface to configure the launch configuration when you get to Storage you will see this:

[image]

You just need to check the "Delete on Termination" checkbox on the right, whenever an instance is terminated the EBS volume associated will be deleted as well.

Comment: I can only access this setting at creation time of the launch configuration but I cannot edit an existing one, right?

Comment: That's right @KostasDemiris, but you can copy a launch configuration, modify it and then replace it on the Autoscaling group, on any new scaling event the new launch configuration should apply.